# Anyway to access hidden folders with Mediastore? (Android)

Tags: android, image, directory, mediastore

I'm trying to make a photo viewer but I'm having trouble with something.

I would like to view folders hidden with a .nomedia file, but Mediastore doesn't seem to scan these folders. Is there anyway to show these folders in the query?

Thanks!